# Pressure cooker delay timer use case

Tags: equipment, pressure-cooker

Many electric pressure cookers, such as my [Power Pressure Cooker XL](http://www.powerpressurecooker.com) come with delay time feature. According to the [manual](http://www.powerpressurecooker.com/downloads/PPC_770_770-1_6QT_IB_TP_ENG_V3_160629.pdf) this can delay cooking by up to 24 hrs. Apparently to accommodate user's schedule. But wouldn't the ingredients spoil by that time? Has anyone used this feature? Am I not getting it right?

Comment: Many vegetables will store under water at room temperature for at least a few hours. 24 was probably chosen as an upper bound for arbitrary reasons

Comment: @ChrisH interestingly enough the "slow cook" timer goes only up to 12 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can give you a couple of delay timer use cases.  I use it A LOT!  The main way I use it is to set-up my oatmeal in a bowl ahead of time ([using this technique](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/pressure-cooker-oatmeal-how-to/)) so it will cook while I sleep and be ready to eat when I wake up. Some also drop tea bags in the steaming water to make tea at the same time - I've tried it out of curiosity it doesn't taste that great (the tea).

Once a week I use it is to set-up a veggie dinner to be ready when I come home late from bringing my kids to after-school activities.  We could be walking in the door at 8:30pm and it's a life-saver to throw some bowls on the table and serve dinner shortly after walking in the door.  The recipes have to be all vegetarian as meat cannot sit in the pressure cooker waiting to cook (even frozen meat). Here are some of my family favorites to have ready for when we just walk in the door

- [Chickpea Curry & Brown Rice One Pot](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/pressure-cooked-chickpea-curry-with-brown-rice-one-pot-meal/)
- [Butternut Squash Soup](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/cream-of-butternut-squash-ginger-soup/) (with garlic bread I've prepared ahead of time)
- [Split Pea & Bacon Soup](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/creamy-split-pea-and-pancetta-soup/) (this is OK because it is cured meat)
- [Sweet Potatoes & Black-eyed Peas One Pot](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/sweet-potato-and-black-eyed-peas-one-pot-meal/)

I hope that these ideas can spur more ideas on how to use the timer.  There are probably more ways but these are the two main ways I use the delay timer on an electric pressure cooker!

Comment: Thanks a lot! W.r.t. cured meat, would hot dogs be ok too?

Comment: No, hot dogs are not cured (salted and dried) but salami is OK.

Answer (score 3):

Dried legumes, and sometimes grains, are commonly soaked 3-24h before pressure cooking them, and this feature would allow useful automation of that method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic behind this feature. You use a pressure cooker to rapidly achieve results similar to cooking something on a very low temperature for a long period of time.

If it has a timer to delay cooking until you come home, for instance, then why wouldn't someone just use a slow cooker instead? Quite baffling to me.

I wouldn't put proteins in it, but vegetables covered in whatever you intend to cook / build pressure with should be okay - could be a great way to time some pickling of stuff now that I think about it.

But as marketed, the feature doesn't seem very useful to me. I'd look for more information from the manufacturer as to the intended use of that particular feature, and if they can't provide any, then just trust your instincts.

Comment: You are assuming that the user has a slow cooker. This is a very rare appliance in most parts of the world.

Comment: And along with people not commonly having slow cookers in some places, recipes in some places commonly use pressure cookers. So if for example you're really familiar with how to do beans in a pressure cooker, you might be more comfortable with "wait 19.5 hours then cook beans half an hour" than "wait 10 hours then cook beans 10 hours."

Comment: It was a bit of an assumption, but I don't think an unfounded one. I've been to many parts of the world and they all had some form of slow cookers. And this particular device being marketed to a part of the world that has an abundance of them makes me wonder a tad bit about the inclusion of that feature :)

Comment: Agreed. Why would a pressure cooker have a slow cook feature?

Comment: Okay. After looking at the product from the provided links, it seems as if it is a pressure cooker with benefits listed as it is quicker than a slow cooker. (Same results but quicker.) This would absolutely make no difference in how long food was left in the cooker *before* cooking started, and if it would be safe.